# What does (3) mean in a font-size value?

Tags: css

I'm trying to understan how [gridlover](http://www.gridlover.net/app/) creates it's grid. In the css it shows:

```
h1{
    font-size: 138px(3)
}
```

What does the (3) mean

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the case of Gridlover, it's just indicating the number of lines that would be covered by that number. You're not meant to take/use the parenthesised number.

You can see that if you grab and drag on the numbers, they go up in steps of the base `line-height`, with the number in the parenthesis going up by 1 each time.

You'll notice that if you select the styles generated by Gridlover, it won't select those numbers in the parenthesis.

Comment: Thanks for the informative answer, otherwise correct, but @kristoffer-nolgren got the math right regarding font-size. On margins, the number in parenthesis does mean the number of lines the value takes.

(I'm the other dude that made Gridlover, that parenthesis thing is getting a better UI treatment soon.)

Answer (score 0):

The parenthesis is not a part of the css, it's a mulitplier.

`The base-font-size*scalefactor^the number in the parenthesis = the font-size for that element.`

This is not a part of css, but rather a part of this app.

Comment: So it does not really appear in a CSS file? Only in something that still has to be processed?

Answer (score 0):

I doubt this is valid CSS code. Check out [the specs](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/fonts.html#propdef-font-size), there is no such syntax. Maybe it is some sort of placeholder that is processed by some other tool, before it is actually delivered to the web browser?

Answer (score 0):

It usually means that you have resized the `h1` Tag here. The original font size is 138px, with the scaled result in parenthesis.